# Logging Drag and Drop Actions of Users

Tags: c#, windows, logging, drag-and-drop

I am trying to figure out a way to log user drag and drop actions across the entire Windows desktop. I've found various mouse hooks which detect what has been clicked and the Windows UI Automation which also helps with this. I wondered if anybody knew any way to log drag and drop events on Windows? At the moment I can detect drags by monitoring the mouse down, move, then up but I believe the key is to actually determine whether the item has been dropped into another object. This has been an ongoing issue for some weeks now and so I could really do with some help pointers on whether this is actually possible and how difficult it is going to be. As I say, I've exhausted many avenues to try and get it working but although I can detect what was dragged (sometimes - due to Windows UI Automation ambiguous names) I cannot determine if it was dropped onto anything and is therefore a drag and drop action?

Many thanks,

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

This is an article about Windows drag and drop action across the Windows Desktop.Please check it

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9017/A-Simple-Drag-And-Drop-How-To-Example

Comment: Is this for detecting drag and drop actions across the whole Windows system? From what I can see, this is drag and drop inside an application which has been written (which I can do). What I'm trying to do is detect drag and drop across any application across the Windows operating system. @linuser